Using the same const both in background.js and in content.js?
The manifest_version is 3. Basically, I am trying to modify tab headers, for specific hosts. In the background.js, I use this structure.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (
    changeInfo.status === "complete") {
    const found = tab_rules.find(item => tab.url.startsWith(item.host));

    if (found != null)
    {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabId },
        files: ["data.js", "content.js"]
      });
    }
  }
});

I would not have need to specify "data.js" before "content.js", if there were a way to pass an argument to "content.js", but there seems no such way, so I need to retrieve the same data in "content.js" in "data.js".
The code above worked for "content.js", but the problem was that I cannot include "data.js" in "background.js". ChatGPT told me 2 methods, but both had a problem.

making it a module and use "import": That worked for "background.js", but then the const in "data.js" needed to be "export", which caused an error when used for "content.js".

"dynamically loading" data.js in background.js: This caused some sort of security error like



Failed to load data.js: EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as
JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in
the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:*
http://127.0.0.1:*".

The only other way that ChatGPT recommanded was using "Storage" to pass the data, but this seems overly complicated. Isn't there any easier way? It's just a constant dictionary object.


Use importScripts() function. 2) To avoid waking up service worker for every tab update consider switching to chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts instead of onUpdated.

